# Regular expression for complicated password

Tags: regex

I want an Regular expression for password that contain

1.It must include at least one uppercase letter and one lowercase letter.

2.It also may include symbols but not these:=?<>()'"/\&.

Here is my regex

/^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])[a-zA-Z,;/~`!@#$%^*-_+~[]{}|]{8,20}$/;

So please give me regular expression.

Comment: Take a look at: http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=password&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: Restricting the use of `=?<>()'"/\&` is just nonsensical. Also asking us for writing code without showing any efforts isn't the way that stackoverflow works.

Comment: I checked that but not found

Comment: You can search and find many useful things, I don't think this is the place for us to do your work !!!

Comment: I had a doubt wheteher, can anyone get a negative reputation. Now I know

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z])(?!.*[:=?<>()'"/\&.]).*
```

`[:=?<>()'"/\&.]` Replace characters between `[` and `]` that you dont want to appear in password

Will match:

```
PassWord
Password+
```

Wont  Match:

```
password
Password<>
```